# Delete Mongoose,Nodejs user at specific time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a question.How to delete mongoose and nodejs user at specifific time? Actually, I want the user to be deleted from the database within 60 days after I remove it.How  I achieve this?

I have added something like Momentjs, how should it go after this? This code should be deleted after 60 days when the user makes a delete operation.

```
suspended: true, 
deleted: moment.utc().valueOf()
```

Answer (score 2):

install any  `cron` package for example `https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule` and in your mongoose model make sure you're storing the created_at timestamp if not just `timestamps:true`. running cron everyday

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });
```

now copy the snippet in your app.js

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 1 * * *', function(){
  return deleteOldUsers();
});
```

assuming your model name is `User` and it's directory is `./models/User`

```
const User = require('./models/User');

deleteOldUsers = () => {
  let current = new Date();
  // subtracting 60 days
  current.setDate(current.getDate() - 60);
  User.deleteMany({ created_at: {$lte: current} }, (err) => {
    if(err) return console.log("Error while erasing users " + err);
    console.log("successfully erased data")
  })
}
```

## EDIT - IF YOU WANT TO USE MOMENT JS INSTEAD OF DATE

```
const User = require('./models/User');
const moment = require('moment');

deleteOldUsers = () => {
 // subtracting 60 days
 let current = moment().subtract(60, 'days');
 current = moment.utc(current).format();
 User.deleteMany({ created_at: {$lte: current} }, (err) => {
   if(err) return console.log("Error while erasing users " + err);
   console.log("successfully erased data")
 })
```

}

Comment: I have added something like Momentjs, how should it go after this? This code should be deleted after 60 days when the user makes a delete operation.

        suspended: true,
        deleted: moment.utc().valueOf()

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific

Comment: I've updated the code if you want to use moment instead of date or is it something else?

Comment: I have a user interface, when the user wants to delete his or her account from this interface, a query occurs in the database

 "deleted" : ISODate("2018-09-27T12:42:04.717Z"),
 "suspended" : true

I want to delete the user from the database if the user doesn't get into account within 60 days, I want

Comment: okay assuming `suspended` is the key name then replace the find query from above to `User.deleteMany({ suspended: true, created_at: {$lte: current} }, ` and now whenever he logs in update his `suspended` status to false.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [TTL (Time To Live)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/index.html) and [partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/):

As of MongoDB 3.2 you could add an expression to the TTL index so that you remove documents only if they match:

```
db.foo.createIndex({createdDate: 1}, {
    expireAfterSeconds: 5184000, // your 60 days
    partialFilterExpression: {
        // Will remove records which have the `isRemoved` flag equal to true
        isRemoved: true
    }
});
```

So the idea here is you would `flag` a user record with `isRemoved` as `true` (default would be `false`) and then this should actually remove it automatically after 60 days.

Comment: I have added something like Momentjs, how should it go after this? This code should be deleted after 60 days when the user makes a delete operation.

        suspended: true,
        deleted: moment.utc().valueOf()