# Cron, Mongoose, NodeJS, Automatically Delete user data if not verified

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to automatically delete user data, only if they have not verified their email within 7 days. I googled and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524766/delete-mongoose-nodejs-user-at-specific-time). I tried & Here is the source code:

**user schema**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, "Please enter your name"],
      max: 32,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, "Please enter your email"],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a valid password"],
      minlength: 8,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    isVerify: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
      data: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

***server.js***

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Web Dev/Portfolio/FullStack/complete-auth-v2/.env",
});

const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const errorHandler = require("./error/errorHandler");
const User = require("./models/userModels");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

app.use("/api", authRoutes);

// >>>>>>> ~ Delete User Data if not verified ~ <<<<<<<
const job = schedule.scheduleJob("*/10 * * * * *", function () {
  return deleteOldUsers();
});

const deleteOldUsers = () => {
  const current = new Date();
  // subtracting 7 days
  // current.setDate(current.getDate() - 7);
  User.deleteMany({ isVerify: false, created_at: { $lte: current } }, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Error while erasing users " + err);
    console.log("successfully erased data");
  });
};
// >>>>>>> ~ Delete User Data if not verified ~ <<<<<<<

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on PORT: ${PORT}`);
});

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
  console.log(`Logged Error: ${err.message}`);
  server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

I am also getting success message in my `console`:
[image]

but my user data is not getting deleted.
[image]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I have not used `cron` before, or if there is any other way of doing the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema uses the [timestamps option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps). From the documentation:

> The timestamps option tells mongoose to assign createdAt and updatedAt fields to your schema. The type assigned is Date.
>
> By default, the names of the fields are createdAt and updatedAt. Customize the field names by setting timestamps.createdAt and timestamps.updatedAt.

In your code, the filter specifies `created_at`, when it should be `createdAt`.